# Function dilatation by 15%

Tags: calculus

Given $f(x) = \sqrt{16 - x^{2}}$

I need to dilate $15\% f(x)$, let's call that $\operatorname{dilf}(x)$.

Is $\operatorname{dilf}(x) = 1.15 \times \left(\sqrt{\left(16 - (\frac {x}{1.15})^{2}\right)}\right)$ the correct answer???

Someone told me that instead of the $1.15$ factor I should use $\frac {1}{0.85}$, but I don't get why.

Comment: Dilation is usually defined by $f_\lambda(x) = f(\lambda x)$, so a dilation (cf. _delay_) by $15\%$ would be
$$f_{0.85}(x) = \sqrt{16 - (0.85x)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks Alex. Just to be sure i'm not understanding it wrong: that wouldn't shrink the function along the x axis??

Comment: That's exactly what this does. It doesn't shrink the graph along the $y$-axis, though.

Comment: No problem. I wrote the comment as an answer so the question can be marked as answered. Feel free to ask for further clarification, if anything remained unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Dilation is usually defined by $f_\lambda(x) = f(\lambda x)$, where a dilation by $15\%$ (cf. *delay*) refers to $\lambda = 1-15\% = 0.85$. This gives
$$f_{0.85}(x) = \sqrt{16-(0.85x)^2}$$
As a solution. Dilation scales (stretches) the functions' graph along the $x$-axis.